# jQuery Validation plugin with JQGrid?

Tags: jquery, validation, jqgrid

Has anyone successfully used the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) with JQGrid? I realize that JQGrid has its own validation scheme, but it's limited and a little clumsy; and I'd prefer to reuse the validation UI, language, and rules that I'm using with the rest of my forms.

Comment: Is jQuery Validation able to validate arbitrary DOM elements (non input/textarea/select)? If yes + you show how I guess it should be possible

Comment: You can use the jQuery validation with JQGrid but there are some caveats.  
One problem is that the jQuery validation adds the error message next to the field you are editing and because of how JQGrid is laid out you can't see the error message.  
The other problem is even if your validation works, JQGrid restores the cell to it's original state when you finish editing.  So if the user makes a mistake, they will have to start over.

Answer (score 4):

Edit inline and Validations is possibile with this steps.

Write your function to highlight and unhilight your input box:

```
GridErrorHighlight = function(el, er, ev) {
    $(el)
        .addClass('ui-state-error')
    .parent()
        .addClass('ui-state-error');
}

GridErrorUnHighlight = function(el, er, ev) {
    $(el)
        .removeClass('ui-state-error')
    .parent()
       .removeClass('ui-state-error');
}
```

Extend jqgrid:

```
; (function($) {
    $.jgrid.extend({
        onErrorHighlight: GridErrorHighlight,
        onUnHighlight: GridErrorUnHighlight,
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Now is easy for jQuery validation plugin use your custom functions. Is only necessary to create this options and initialize validation plugin:

```
var table = $('#tableid').jqGrid({});

var validateOpt = {
        meta: "validate",
        highlight: table.onErrorHighlight,
        unhighlight: table.onUnHighlight
    };

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formId').validate(val);
});
```

Now is easy to set validator for single input cell.
We use jqGrid EditOptions into Model to add custom class for validation:

```
"editoptions":{"class":" {validate: { range:[0,1] } }"}
```

that's all!